# Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined in svelte

Tags: javascript, leaflet, svelte, svelte-3

below is my code. I am using leaflet in svelte to plot a map with image.

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import L from "leaflet";
  var map;
  onMount(() => {
    map = L.map("issmap").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  });
  var imageUrl = "http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg",
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
  L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
</script>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>
    <style>
      #issmap {
        height: 180px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="issmap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting a error "Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined". How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your problem is that you try to use `map` outside the `onMount` callback so it is `undefined` in the line:

```js
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

To fix it just add it to the `onMount` callback:

```js
  onMount(() => {
    map = L.map("issmap").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    var imageUrl = "http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg",
      imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
  });
```

Checkout the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-montalcini-2f0ie?file=/App.svelte).

Comment: now I am not getting the error but I am not able to see the image or the layer either.

Comment: I am just getting blank leaflet map with zoom in and out option.

Comment: It works with default example of leaflet checkout [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-blackwell-xkir9?file=/App.svelte). So the error is not related to svelte anymore. Please don't forget to also upvote this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But Instead of using openstreetmap , can you please tell me how can I add image/floorplan.